# Control php output and post it as it occurs

Tags: php

I am just a amateur php programmer!
I have a specific requirement.

I want to control php output behaviour in my script.

What i want is this thing

myscript.php

```
echo "phase 1";// (output to browser immediately)
echo "Proceeding further....";
sleep (10);
echo "phase 2";// (output to the browser immediately)
sleep(10);
echo "phase end";
```

But what happens is all the output of echo gets dump after 20 second i mean complete output not sequencewise...
How can i output it in sequence wise.. i do not know what it is called ! Please also show a example if possible it helps in understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at some Websocket like [Rachet](http://socketo.me/). For a simpler version, you just use a combination of Javascript/Ajax and PHP.

## EDIT: The simplest way; the jQuery/PHP way

As requested in the comments, this is a very simple, insecure way of achieving asynchronous server work/feedback.

### Server-side

```
//doTheWork.php
switch($_POST['step'])
{
     case 1:
         $output = shell_exec('cat text.txt'); //Do whatever you need to do here
         break;
     case 2:
         $output = shell_exec('ls');
         break;
     default:
         $output = "No or invalid step declared";
}

echo $output;
```

### Client-side

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Testing live feedback</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!-- Include your local version of jQuery -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="console">
            <h2>Output from server</h2>
            <div id="console_output">

            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var totalSteps = 5;
            var currentStep = 0;
            var url_to_server = "http://localhost/doTheWork.php";


            function executeAndOutputData()
            {
                currentStep++;

                if(currentStep >= totalSteps) return;

                $.post(url_to_server, {step:currentStep}, function(response){
                    $("#console_output").append(response+"<br>");
                    executeAndOutputData();
                });
            }

            executeAndOutputData();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Can't it be done wholelly and solely just by php ?     2)I really do not have exp to implement rachet or whatever it is ... So can you provide a simple example with my code and scenario ?

Comment: Well, if you want to acheive what you're asking but you do not want to put your back into it, you won't succeed. PHP is simply not built for this kind of task (it's pretty advanved stuff). PHP/REST is meant to be asynchronous: Client sends a request -> Server interprets the request and does the work -> Server sends response, which client interprets; communication is over until the next request is sent.

Comment: So basically: If you want to do do something that outputs sequencially, you'll have to make a request for every output or establish an ongoing connection between the server and the client. Or you could make use of buffer flushing like Kevin Labécot mentioned. Alternatively, take a look at Pusher: http://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start

Comment: But honestly - asynchronous outputting is not for beginners / "amateur php programmers", as you said it.

Comment: Hey thank you I agree with you...but now it is like i m going to Kinder garden to learn new technology... Can you provide a very very easy to understand and where to start guide/video etc. which will help me make simple interface for mobile app (just browser specific not android)?

Comment: Use half an hour to look at Pusher: http://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start. That's the simplest solution that also works in a production environment.

Comment: I would also like to tell you that my main aim is to run os shell script and get the recurring output to webpage.. what you suggest should i look into ?

Comment: Pusher would be sufficient.

Comment: but isn't pusher require active internet connection (((e.g You first need to establish a connection to Pusher. This is done by using your application key (app_key).)))... my req is to work inside intranet... the website is not available over the internet.

Comment: Ok, then pusher isn't the way to go. Let me just provide an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can natively with PHP using flush functions.

Example with your code :

```
<?
echo "phase 1";// (output to browser immediately)
echo "Proceeding further....";
flush();
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_flush();
sleep (10);
echo "phase 2";// (output to the browser immediately)
sleep(10);
echo "phase end";

?>
```

edit : But, this is just to answer you. A such code is certainly fully useless and must be improved to remove `sleep` calls.

Comment: Buffer flushing is maybe even more volatile as it requires some server knowledge to work properly.

Comment: Hey thankyou for the answer it was direct answer to my question... But i think i am looking for websocket... lol and again thank you i thought of ob_start and stuff like that but i was not sure on how to use it in my case...

Comment: When i tested it didn't work why ? i am using latest wamp server... it just dumped the output after 20sec as usual..

Comment: As I stated in my first comment, output buffer flushing requires server setup, that's why it doesn't work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I am satisfied with Dencker answer but still i now know a simpler way by using only PHP.
Derived from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/680085/Real-time-Updating-of-PHP-Output

```
// Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

//Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
while (@ob_end_flush());

// Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
ob_implicit_flush(true);

echo "Start<br />";

echo str_pad("",1024," ");
echo "<br />";

ob_flush();
flush();

sleep(5);        

echo "Program Output";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

And it does work without any server config and it is well suited for my need (temp). But i will be looking at the suggestion posted here.